# ASP.NET MVC iterate through collection within collection

Tags: asp.net-mvc, data-binding

I have an ASP.NET MVC app in which I am iterating through a Linq result set. Each row in the result set contains a property which is an EntitySet itself. When I try to iterate through the inner result set, I get an error message: "Invalid object name EntitySetOfSubItem" when trying to load the page. How do I process this collection?

```
<% foreach item in Model { %>
    ... code
    <% foreach subitem in item.EntitySetOfSubItems { %>
```

Comment: You are correct. The actual code has (); consider it a transcription error on the author's part.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would do it something like this:

```
<% foreach(YourType item in Model) { %>
    ... code
    <% foreach(OtherType subitem in item.EntitySetOfSubItems) { %>
```

By typing the iteration variable, you inform the compiler what attributes are available on the subitem.

Comment: I tried that and am now getting a compilation error stating that "The type or namespace name 'OtherType' could not be found (are you missing a directive or an assembly reference?)"

Comment: Ok -- gave fully qualified AssemblyName.Models.OtherType and now am back to the original error message.

    foreach (AssemblyName.Models.OtherType subitem ...)

Comment: Well, if that is the case, your "OtherType" probably doesn't actually have that property.  Could you "navigate to" the "OtherType" and verify that there is actually an "EntitySetOfSubItems" property?

Comment: In my Model, the property is definitely of type EntitySet<OtherType>. When I hover over item.EntitySetOfSubItems in the view page, it states the same thing.

Comment: I think I have a deeper problem. Let me check on something else.

Comment: My apologies. I have an error occurring in my db code that is not giving an exception so I do not have an item of OtherType in YourType. I'm going to accept your answer because it appears to be correct though not the solution to my real problem.